# NodeJS App crashes when wrong parameters are passed to the API

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, express

I have created an CRUD API using typescript NodeJS, Express and MongoDB. What I am trying to achieve is that when using the POST method when I send the correct parameter. API works fine. However whenever I send incorrect parameters to the API the whole NodeJS app crashes, I get an error message in console that the parameters passed to the API are wrong and I will have restart the application again.

When as user sends the incorrect parameters to the API. I don't want the NodeJS app to crash. I want to display the useful error message. Keep the app running. I Don't want to restart the application.

This is the code i use to create New providers.

```
    public addProviders(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

    var type = req.body.type,
        name = req.body.name;

    let newProvider = new Provider({
        type,
        name
    })

    newProvider.save()
        .then((provider: Object) => {
            if (provider) {
                let statusCode = res.statusCode;
                res.json({
                    statusCode,
                    provider
                })
            }
        })
}
```

Below is the code that i have tried so far.

```
        try {
    newProvider.save()
        .then((provider: Object) => {
            if (provider) {
                let statusCode = res.statusCode;
                res.json({
                    statusCode,
                    provider
                })
            }
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        res.json("enter valid parameters")
    }
```

I am new to NodeJS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wrap your function/logic in a [`try...catch` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), and if it errors out you can handle it in any way you want, rather than your whole application crashing. And for NodeJS you can also intercept errors on an application level with `process.on('unhandledRejection'...)` for example.

Comment: You should either change .save().then() to `await newProvider.save()` and then try/catch, or add a `.catch` continuation after the `.then`

Comment: @decho Thanks for commenting. Could you please give me an in reference to the above code. I have edited the question and added what i have tried with try catch block.the nodeJs app still crashs when I pass the wrong parameters.

Comment: @JustAG33K perhaps try to wrap the whole function between a try catch? Like `public addProviders() { ... try { ... } catch { ... } }`. Also, the error that you are receiving, it should point you out to the exact line number and location where the first error occurs so you can trace it.

Comment: I have tried both your solutions however i am not getting the desired results. I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: did the answer work with you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add input validation middleware to check inputs before adding to Database.

**#1** You can check it manually, like:

```
var { type, name } = req.body;

if (typeof type !== 'string') {
    res.status(400).send("type input is not valid");

} else if (typeof name !== 'string') {
    res.status(400).send("name input is not valid");

} else {
    let newProvider = new Provider({
        type,
        name
    })
    // ...rest of the code
}
```

**#2** Or you can use a package like `express-validator`.